# Multi-Tenant Azure AD B2C - Profile Photo or Thumbnail from parent AD

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have a working implementation of the [Azure AD B2C multi-tenant custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-commonaad-custom?tabs=applications) in the Identity Experience Framework.

I'm trying to get profile photos populated in the B2C tenant when a new user signs in. Is this possible?

If so, can you help me determine the correct `PartnerClaimType` to persist?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass through the access_token from Azure AD to your application and perform a Graph API call to obtain it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-user-flow?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Thank you, Jamie. If I understand correctly, this will let me get the photo per user session. Would I then save it as a base64 string in an extension property of my B2C tenant? Or do you know if it could it be saved to the `Photo` property of the B2C user? My goal is allow an admin to view all users (with profile photo if it exists).